# Grouping specific observations under the same name in a data frame and adding their values

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, grouping

Have the following df. I need to transform the 2nd variable  where all the observations named (Albania, Andorra and Angola) are grouped under the observation named GROUP. (and adding their related values in the 3rd variable. I have to the do the same thing for different groups of countries.

```
           reporter                                    partner         value

    df> 1   Rep. of Korea                                World    162466097148
        2   Rep. of Korea                          Afghanistan       127909338
        3   Rep. of Korea                              Albania         2715507
        4   Rep. of Korea                              Algeria       186447452
        5   Rep. of Korea                       American Samoa        17835666
        6   Rep. of Korea                              Andorra         3583727
        7   Rep. of Korea                               Angola        18543519
        8   Rep. of Korea                  Antigua and Barbuda        50962013
        9   Rep. of Korea                           Azerbaijan         3783982
        10  Rep. of Korea                            Argentina        51471247
```

Comment: Hi,
please add your desired output on a representative portion of your data

Answer (score 1):

if your dataframe is called `df` and the country column is named `GROUP` and the third column is named `numbers`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(GROUP) %>%
summarize(SUM = sum(numbers, na.rm = T))
```

edit:
Assuming the column `partners` is a character column:

```
library(magrittr)

groupNames = c("Albania", "Andorra", "Angola")
GROUP = df[df$partner %in% groupNames, "value"] %>% sum
newdf = rbind(df,
              data.frame(reporter = "", partner =  "GROUP", value =  GROUP))
```

if you want the GROUP vector to be a new column

Comment: "group" must replace the name of the observation whenever it calls" Albania, Andorra and Angola"

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, you should add a way for us to understand how each column is named since its not clear from your sample data.

Comment: @AndreaDallaRosa take a look at my edit at the bottom